# Error reports in distributed desktop app do not contain line numbers for code in supporting dll

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a desktop application that reports exceptions when they occur. The solution contains the main project in VB.net and a supporting project in C#. When debugging on my machine the error reports contain the stack trace with line numbers. However, when I get an error report from a customer only the VB code returns line numbers. Both PDB files are included in the distribution. In Visual Studio's Setup Project's File System display both are in the Application Folder though the C# PDB is marked as Read Only while the VB.net is not.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not supposed to get line numbers for the VB.NET code either.  Be sure to deploy the Release build of the project.  Project > Properties > Compile tab, Advanced button, "Generate debug info" is full for the Debug build, pdb-only for the Release build.  The latter has the line number info stripped because it is unreliable in the optimized Release build.  This typically goes wrong because you added a file reference instead of a project reference to the vb.net project.

Comment: Thanks Hans. On reflection, sometimes the line numbers in error reports from clients get me to the rough area rather than what is clearly the line where the exception occurred. I suppose I'll have to live with it and concentrate on error prevention and handling.